# Redis standalone server or with MySQL

Tags: mysql, redis, server

I am trying to build a site which needs to server a large number or read requests. There is no write from users. I would like use MySQL as my backend server and redis as my cache layer.

The size of data is 60 GB. I have 8 EC2 which has 2core and 6GB RAM. My thought is to use redis to store as many data as possible .However I wonder that what should be the right number of redis server and mysql server. Since the total site of data is only 60GB, if I can have 8 redis sever which can hold around 40GB data. So it is not possible to only use redis.

Option 1: shard data evenly to 7 servers which has both MySQL and redis. Each servers stores around 10GB data in MySQL and redis stores 4-5GB data  (The instance only has 6 GB RAM). I will have one server to do load balance and point to the right server which stores that value.

Option 2: shard my data to 2 servers with MySQL, and other 5 servers are redis servers which store data from those 2 servers.  And one front end server to do load balance to point to right redis server. If redis server does not find anything, then it will read data from MySQL server?

When I use the single MySQL server, the latency is around 100ms. I want to reduce latency significantly, thats why I come up with those approaches .

I do not have much experience of backend architecture. Any help or any new idea is appreciated.

Comment: this site is for programming questions. we are not here to recommend a server infrastructure for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work like this.

What you miss in both of your options is some backend software. Redis and MySQL are independent data stores. Redis will not fetch data from MySQL in case of cache miss.

You also need to evaluate your working set: the percentage of your data which will be accessed frequently, and therefore have to be served from the cache.

You need a load balancer. You also need to write a server software which tries to fetch the data first from Redis, and in case of miss, execute a query to MySQL, and then provide Redis with the result. It probably also has to sustain some cache invalidation traffic.

Personally, I would not shard MySQL at all. Managing a database is time consuming - do not shard it until you actually need it. Since you are on EC2, I would just use RDS instances (so that high-availability of the data can be guaranteed). Then, I would use the Elastic Load Balancer to distribute the traffic to n nodes, each of them containing a Redis instance, plus the backend software processing the traffic. The data in Redis would be sharded using a consistent hashing algorithm to limit the impact of the potential failure of these nodes.

There are many ways to implement your requirements - this is just an example.